# Connection Timeout Expired - [Pre-Login] initialization=43; handshake=29988;

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I am failing to connect to this **SQL Server 2019 using a fully qualified database server name,21433**.  This has been working for over 18 months.  There is a new network changes.  The rule for mapping 21433 is active.

**The connection fails when I use Verizon's gateway network but when I tether my sprint phone it works.**

*The error below:
Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=43; handshake=29988;  (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Palo Alto VPN.

1. When it was enabled, it blocked any port other 3389.
2. When it was disabled, I could connect to the port 21433 worked perfectly.  The downside
   as I could not rdp because the Palo Alto VPN was disabled.

It will be fixed by properly configuring the Palo Alto VPN.